# Setted attribute with setattr is different type than given value in Python (Django)

Tags: python, django

Since [ArrayField does not work with FileField](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25756) in Django, I'm trying to fix it. However, I came up to a [line of code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9a2a12d415e6d224797b0779c5af03deb8c45b0a/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L317), where I don't understand, how it happens, that setted attribute using `setattr` becomes different type than given value.

To be exact - if I add print lines to [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9a2a12d415e6d224797b0779c5af03deb8c45b0a/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L317):

```
print(data)
setattr(instance, self.name, data or '') # line 317 
print(getattr(instance, self.name)
```

Here's what I get when I save a Model with FileField:

```
<class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.TemporaryUploadedFile'>
<class 'django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile'>
```

What happens here?

Comment: This is a descriptor. See the [comment at the start of the class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9a2a12d415e6d224797b0779c5af03deb8c45b0a/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L214).

Comment: Both are subclasses of `File`. Before you assign it to a `FileField`, it's a `TemporaryUploadedFile`, which is what you get from `request.FILES`. Next with `getattr` you're access the file field, Django [gives you a `FieldFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile) "as a proxy for accessing the underlying file". Remember, a model `Field` isn't just a simple instance variable, it has getters and setters to map the data you give to a database representation and vice versa.